# One Build - multiple outputs (64/32 Bit )

Tags: x86, build-automation, 64-bit, tfsbuild

One of projects in our solution references a third party .NET C++ assembly which exists as 64 and 32 bit version. As we wanna provide our application for 32 & 64 bit systems we currently start two Builds (TFS 2008/Team Build) while each build is given a different value for property "PlatformTarget" which decides whether to reference the 64 or 32 Bit C++ assembly (all other projects are C# Code). Is there a best practice how to customize a BuildType so we get a 64/32 Bit Version by just one Build, i.e. compile a 64/32 Bit Version in one Build?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out: All you got to do is to create an BuildConfig in the solutions file (which is inherited to the projects (csproj)) and use those in the BuidlType-definition (TFSBuild.proj)

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release32|x86">
  <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
  <PlatformToBuild>x86</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>

<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release64|x64">
  <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
  <PlatformToBuild>x64</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
```